# SQL Server - How to combine one-to-many into a single table

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of contacts that I want to be able to connect to a contacts_phone table which has an arbitrary number of phones for a given contact.  But when I query I want to have a list of contacts with all available phone numbers.  Is this possible?

Contacts table

| id | FirstName | LastName | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liam | Smith |  |
| 2 | Noah | Johnson |  |
| 3 | Oliver | Williams |  |

Contacts_Phone table

| id | ContactsId | Phone | PhoneType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 212-555-1234 | Home |
| 2 | 1 | 212-555-2314 | Cell |
| 3 | 2 | 332-555-1324 | Cell |
| 4 | 3 | 212-555-1432 | Cell |
| 5 | 3 | 332-555-4213 | Work Cell |
| 6 | 3 | 347-555-4321 | Work |
| 7 | 3 | 212-555-4231 | Alt |

Desired result

| id | FirstName | LastName | etc | Phone1 | Phone2 | Phone3 | Phone4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liam | Smith |  | 212-555-1234 | 212-555-2314 |  |  |
| 2 | Noah | Johnson |  | 332-555-1324 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Oliver | Williams |  | 212-555-1432 | 332-555-4213 | 347-555-4321 | 212-555-4231 |

Comment: I did include expected results.  I don't know what to try, sorry.

Comment: If you have an absolute maximum number of `Phone` columns that you can tell me, then we can do this without dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

You will need a more complex dynamic SQL solution to achieve the result exactly like you asked for.

However, here is a non-dynamic SQL solution that may work for you. It basically is using a subquery for each phone type.

```
select c.id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.etc, 
  (select Phone from Contacts_Phone as cp where cp.ContactsId = c.id and PhoneType = 'Home') as HomePhone,
  (select Phone from Contacts_Phone as cp where cp.ContactsId = c.id and PhoneType = 'Cell') as CellPhone,
  (select Phone from Contacts_Phone as cp where cp.ContactsId = c.id and PhoneType = 'Work Cell') as WorkCellPhone,
  (select Phone from Contacts_Phone as cp where cp.ContactsId = c.id and PhoneType = 'Work') as WorkPhone,
  (select Phone from Contacts_Phone as cp where cp.ContactsId = c.id and PhoneType = 'Alt') as AltPhone 
from Contacts as c
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know how many phone numbers a contact may have, so I can't be sure how many subqueries I would need to make